# Switching "tabs" with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create something like tabs.
So I have tab itself as

```
    <div class="tab" >Tab1</div>
    <div class="tab" >Tab2</div>
    <div class="tab" >Tab3</div>
```

and page content for each tab as

```
    <div class="pagecontent" >pagecontent for Tab1</div>
    <div class="pagecontent" >pagecontent for Tab2</div>
    <div class="pagecontent" >pagecontent for Tab3</div>
```

How to make js function in "clever way" so by pressing "tab1", "pagecontent for Tab1"  shows and other 2 get hidden? Also, number of tabs varies from page to page.

Comment: Possibly it would be better to use http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: @FAngel I wouldn't recommend including an entire library for the functionality the OP has requested.

Comment: @BenM that is why it starts with "Possibly" ;) At the same time - it has a lot more than just simple show/hide and possibly OP will find it useful (if he knew nothing about it before). Or not. That is why it is not an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function() {  
    $('.pagecontent').not(':eq(0)').hide();
    $('.tab').click(function() {  
        $('.pagecontent').hide();
        $('.pagecontent').eq($(this).index()).show();
    });  
});
```

Please see a working demo here > http://jsfiddle.net/Yce32/

Comment: Nice. But, please, cache your selectors.

Comment: It really makes very little difference with the amount of DOM elements we're dealing with here.

Comment: Fair enough, but it's good practice. And we don't know OP's full DOM in this case. OP wrote: *number of tabs varies from page to page*, so there might be 20 tabs with loads of elements.

Comment: it acts in an amusing way. let's say page looks like     `<div id="ll">sometext</div>
 <div class="tab" >Tab1</div>
    <div class="tab" >Tab2</div>
    <div class="tab" >Tab3</div>
    <div class="pagecontent" >pagecontent for Tab1</div>
    <div class="pagecontent" >pagecontent for Tab2</div>
    <div class="pagecontent" >pagecontent for Tab3</div>` then clicking on tab1 brings pagecontent2 and clicking on tab2 brings pagecontent3. clicking on tab3 does nothing. check demo http://jsfiddle.net/Yce32/3/

Comment: @Flyer it uses `.index()` to check which tab has been clicked. This doesn't work when you added another div before tabs. You can either use `.index()` with selector like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfrej/Yce32/5/) or wrap your tabs in some container like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfrej/Yce32/4/).

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery UI Tabs:

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

It's "clever way" - you will have add\delete\order tabs in a box